# Excel IF formula tweak/adjustments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to get IF formula working. I am trying but I keep getting the error "too many parameters" Can anyone help?

=IF(A1<=90, "2", "", IF(A1>=91,"3","",if(A1<=109,"3","",if(A1>=110,"4","",if(A1>=120,"5","")))))

Trying to get it to state anything below 90% is a 2 score, from 91%  to 109% is a 3, 110 to 120% is a 4, and above 120 is a 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You are using 4 parameters. You can use max. 3 parameters in *IF* function.

```
=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

In your case, you should use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=0,A1<=90),"2",IF(AND(A1>90,A1<110),"3",IF(AND(A1>=110,A1<=120),"4",IF(A1>120,"5",""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have four sets of parameters for many of your ifs.

It should probably be:

```
=IF(A1<=90, "2", if(A1<=109, "3", if(A1<=120, "4", "5")))
```

Comment: Thanks Herb. I tried the above you've mentioned but I formula doesn't return the values like it should. it seems it's only getting the first IF result, "2" regardless of the value range (90-120). Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: I was just doing it off the top of my head, as I'm on my linux machine. I made a couple of changes to make it shorter/simpler.